# How would I be able to generate route 53 aliases for MSK bootstrap servers?

Tags: apache-kafka, terraform, amazon-route53

I can create a single bootstrap server alias for Kafka as follows.

```
resource "aws_msk_cluster" "kafka" {
  count        = var.kafka_number_of_broker_nodes > 0 ? 1 : 0
  ...
}

# This generates a single bootstrap DNS entry which are used by the Kafka client for simplicity
resource "aws_route53_record" "kafka" {
  count   = var.kafka_number_of_broker_nodes > 0 ? 1 : 0
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.internal.zone_id
  name    = "corekafka"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [split(":", sort(split(",", aws_msk_cluster.kafka[0].bootstrap_brokers))[0])[0]]
}
```

However, for fault tolerance, I would like to be able to specify all the bootstrap broker DNS names.  I had the following code but if the kafka gets busted, usually on a test environment and the disk becomes full, if I won't be able to simply taint the kafka and need to manually remove the DNS entries first using the console or `terraform -destroy`

```
# This generates bootstrap DNS entries which are used by the Kafka client for better load balancing
resource "aws_route53_record" "kafka-bootstrap" {
  zone_id  = aws_route53_zone.internal.zone_id
  for_each = { for i, s in sort(split(",", aws_msk_cluster.kafka[0].bootstrap_brokers)) : s => [split(":", s)[0], i + 1] }
  name     = "b${each.value[1]}.corekafka"
  type     = "CNAME"
  ttl      = "300"
  records  = [each.value[0]]
}
```

Is there anything I can change on the block above to make it handle taints of the kafka server?

Comment: Unclear why you need to remove entries from DNS. The Kafka client bootstrap protocol already round-robins the requests to healthy brokers. More specifically, dead brokers will be removed by the Kafka Controller. And the Kafka protocol already "load balances" itself.

Comment: because when I taint the kafka so it can be rebuilt (usually with a smaller size again) it won't let me because it's associated with the route 53 DNS names.

Comment: If you are rebuilding without worrying about data loss, why not just destroy and recreate?

Comment: because I don't want to destroy the whole thing I still want the rest of my EC2 and RDS and other configs. just don't care about the data in kafka.

Comment: In that case, it may make more sense to separate your Kafka provider definitions (and statefile) from your other resources so terraform wont destroy those as well. Regardless, the DNS entries probably don't need removed unless the whole Kafka cluster itself is being destroyed since the Kafka client protocol (and the underlying OS TCP requests) should know how to round-robin the DNS over remaining/existing brokers.

Answer (score 0):

This removes the `for_each` and uses the broker node count.  So it avoids the dependency.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "kafka-bootstrap" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.internal.zone_id
  count   = var.kafka_number_of_broker_nodes
  name    = "b${count.index + 1}.corekafka"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [split(":", sort(split(",", aws_msk_cluster.kafka[0].bootstrap_brokers))[count.index])[0]]
}
```